# how to select element from dropdown/address list API

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, dropdown

import select
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
s=Service("C:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")   #excutable service patch
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://app.mondofi.co/")

driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/form/div[1]/div/input').send_keys("stage_mondofi")
#print(type(userEle))
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/form/div[2]/div/input').send_keys("Z3Pytzsh56eQSZmH")

driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/form/div[3]/button').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a').click()
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div[2]/div/div/input').send_keys("Ash")
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div[3]/div/div/input').send_keys("Ish")
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div[4]/div/div/input').send_keys("ash@yopmail.com")
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div[5]/div/div/input').send_keys(9418035364)
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div[6]/div/div/input').send_keys("Lake View")
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div[7]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys("Lake")
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/input').send_keys("Surrey")
select.select('Surrey, BC, Canada')

Answer (score 0):

You should use the selenium select class

for example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get('url')

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id(select_id))

# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text(write the items to appear)

# select by value 
select.select_by_value(item value)
```

**if using xpath:**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='element_name']/option[text()='option_text']").click()
```